# How browsers group cookies in the development tools

Tags: web, cookies, browser

Visiting the website https://repubblica.it and looking, in the development tools, at the Cookie section I can see that some cookies, of a different domain, are listed under the same "page" of a different one. For example have a look at this:

[image]

[image]

Here I'm under the "page" https://www.repubblica.it but I can see cookies for a domain other than "repubblica.it", for example "taboola.com". I was expecting to see under the "Cookie" section an item named "https://taboola.com" with all the cookies for this domain.

So, how cookies are group?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are now isolating cookies by which site is open. Third party cookies set by images and scripts no longer track users across sites.

Browser tools now list third party cookies under the first party site that was open when they were set.

For example in Firefox this is called [Total Cookie Protection](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2021/02/23/total-cookie-protection/).

Comment: I did some experiments and I've noticed that cookies set by JS files or images show up in the same page as the first-party site, whereas cookies set by iframes show up under a new page titled with a different domain. Is it right? Is there any particular sense?

Comment: That sounds like a privacy flaw in whatever browser you tested with.

Comment: I conducted the experiments on Google Chrome

Comment: Just to be cleaner. That's what I did. If, on my site https://a.com/index.php I load as script/img the URL https://b.com/index.php and this last pages created a cookie, then this cookie shows up under Cookies > https://a.com. Whereas if I load as iframe the same URL, then thr cookie shows up under Cookies > https://b.com. Is there any particular reason?

Comment: Chrome is lagging behind other browsers.  3rd party cookies won't be totally disable until 2024. https://www.cookiebot.com/en/google-third-party-cookies/  Not sure why that browser is currently treating iframe and js cookies differently.

Comment: On Firefox, instead, if on my site a.com/index.php I load as script/img the URL b.com/index.php and this last page sets a cookie, then this cookie is completaly ignored. Whereas if I load as iframe the same URL, then the cookie shows up under Cookies > b.com. This happens also with Enhanced Tracking Protection disabled. Is Firefox blocking cookie creation the URL are used in tags that are different than iframe?